# Creating short code for search form

Tags: forms

I added this snippet in my functions.php file but it doesn't execute the categories from foreach. It only shows the keywords field and it works fine but it's not showing the categories names.

```
function jobsform_function($atts) {  
    return '
      <form class="home-job-search" method="GET" action="https://website.com/jobs/jobs/">
        <div class="home-keywords">
          <input type="text" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" placeholder="Enter Keywords" />
        </div>
        <div class="home-categories">
          <select id="search_category" name="search_category">
              <?php foreach ( get_job_listing_categories() as $cat ) : ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->term_id ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?>
                 </option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="home-search-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
      </form>';
}
add_shortcode('jobsform', 'jobsform_function');
```

the HTML is not reading the foreach query

```
<form class="home-job-search" method="GET" action="https://design.muntomedia.com/jobs/jobs/">
            <div class="home-keywords">
                <input type="text" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
            </div>
            <div class="home-categories">
                <select id="search_category" name="search_category">
                    <!--?php foreach ( get_job_listing_categories() as $cat ) : ?-->
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->term_id ); ?>">
                            <!--?php echo esc_html( $cat--->name ); ?>;
                        </option>
                    <!--?php endforeach; ?-->;
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="home-search-button">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
```

this is the result
[image: search form]
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the rendered HTML to your question?

Comment: I updated the post with the HTML Code

Comment: The problem is the structure `return '<somehtml><?php .. ?><morehtml>';` which is not possible. You're already inside PHP, no need to for the open and close tags.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the shortcode content as a big string, your function `get_job_listing_categories` is not properly being called.

Also i would recommend use PHP output buffering which is great for WordPress shortcodes.

Try below code:

```
function jobsform_function($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
      <form class="home-job-search" method="GET" action="https://website.com/jobs/jobs/">
        <div class="home-keywords">
          <input type="text" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" placeholder="Enter Keywords" />
        </div>
        <div class="home-categories">
          <select id="search_category" name="search_category">
              <?php foreach (get_job_listing_categories() as $cat): ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($cat->term_id); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html($cat->name); ?>
                 </option>
              <?php endforeach;?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="home-search-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
      </form>
<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('jobsform', 'jobsform_function');
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with me